# Smart guide helper text not shown when hovering over an anchor point

Tags: adobe-illustrator, guides

On Illustrator CC 2017, after I turn on smart guides (CTRL+U) when I move the cursor over an anchor point it shows a strange small gray shape rather than the green text that was shown in CS6.

How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't really replicate the issue you seem to be having. Perhaps check the `Anchor/Path Labels` option is checked in your preferences - see screenshot below.

In AI CC 2017, my default colour for the Smart Guide labels are magenta.

[image: Example Screenshot]

However the colour can be changed in Preferences > Smart Guides, to any colour you want.

[image]

Comment: I also could suggest checking the checkBoxes to enable the desired label.